# Is there a word for "skull" in Klingon?

Tags: translation, klingon

Exactly what it says on the can - I'm looking for a word in `tlhingan-Hol` (Klingon) for "skull".

Fallback: In case there isn't a canon word, I'm defaulting to using "head bone" as a replacement. I know from TKD that `nach` is "head" and `Hom` is "bone". Is this combination `nach Hom` correct? e.g. is `jaghpu'ma' nach HomDu'` a reasonable translation for "our enemies' skulls"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Update from 2022]

Turns out the word was (semi-officially?) added to the lexicon a few months after the question and @Richard's answer - at **qepHom** 2019 (an annual meeting of Klingonists in Germany).

### The word for "skull" is `DughrI'`

(Added on 11/17/2019)

See kli.com [New Klingon Words (not in the original lexicon)](https://www.kli.org/about-klingon/new-klingon-words/datemodified/) page as citation.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, there doesn't seem to be any canon word for "skull" in Klingon, so a compound should be fine.

Note, however, that some compounds are constructed without separation between their parts (see for example [Wiktionary's list of Klingon compound words](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:Klingon_compound_words)) with no apparent rule as to why, so "skull" could conceivably be `nachHom`.

BUT, since `-Hom` is also the diminutive suffix, `nachHom` would primarily mean "little skull", making `nach Hom` is the less ambiguous translation.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to wikitionary "words by etymology" - never thought there's such a resource. I think that since there's a diminutive suffix '-Hom', 'nachHom' would be read as "smallhead" rather than "skull"

Comment: @G0BLiN I definitely should have checked that before answering. In this case, 'nach Hom' is better, I think.

Comment: Richard - maybe edit your answer to reflect on why `nachHom` may not be suitable in this case? Comments aren't permanent, but this insight is relevant to the answer.